# PHP string assign to array variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have written some php code, trying what is to assign a string (tag_of_organization) to a variable and then latter to assign it to array newvar. As i am totally new to php and search a lot for it but cannot find anything, so i am asking it here how to do this. here it is

```
$organ='tag_of_organization';  
$newvar = array(); 
$newvar["tag_of_organization"] =$organ;
```

Comment: Yes, and...? What is the problem or question?

Comment: @abid: Can't help asking: What would be the use of that? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @geomagas Story is long i am writing this code to check for two ids in two tables actually this code runs on the request coming from android code when the id matches in one of the two tables i want to assign it a string that will tell the android that from which table it is. This string will be use in android code in if condition on which the android code will decide to open the related activity. All is ok but i am in doubt about the above code.

Comment: Ok, next question: You need it in a different format than what you already have? Because, from where I'm standing, you're answering your own question. Could you elaborate? _(preferably by editing/extending the question)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already correct. put `print_r` to test print your array

```
$organ='tag_of_organization';  
$newvar = array(); 
$newvar["tag_of_organization"] =$organ;
print_r($newvar);
```

Output

```
Array ( [tag_of_organization] => tag_of_organization )
```

Update

you want dynamic result

```
$organ='tag_of_organization';  
$newvar = array(); 
$newvar[$organ] =$organ;
print_r($newvar);
```

Output

```
Array ( [tag_of_organization] => tag_of_organization )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$newvar[$organ] = $organ;
```